# Gitlab 6.4 not pushing to correct repository directory

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab

I'm in the process in migrating from GitLab 6.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 to GitLab 6.4.3 on CentOS 6.5.

I followed [these](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/install/centos) instructions and everything is up, but I have two issues:

1. When creating a new project and trying to push to it via `git push -u origin master` I get the error `fatal: asc/project-name.git does not appear to be a git repository`. I double checked to make sure it was, and it is. I then tried the absolute path `/home/git/repositories/asc/project-name.git` and it works.

   So I think, easy enough just a configuration issue...but where? `/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml` has `repos_path: /home/git/repositories/`.
2. The second issue is on the GitLab 6.4 homepage, no project history shows up.

Ideas?

Also, I'm using MySQL as the database, and nginx as the web-server.

Comment: you said you tried absolute path, tried it where or how exactly ?

Comment: In my existing git repo config file. I'm pushing an existing repo to GitLab.

[remote "origin"]
url= git@hostname.domain:asc/projec-name.git
url= git@hostname.domain:/home/git/repositories/asc/projecname.git

Comment: The fist url= does not work but the second one with the absolute path does work.